# Solr weird search behaviour

Tags: solr, pysolr

I am having lots of solr document indexed which has field

```
uri = nntp://msnews.microsoft.com/microsoft.public.windows.server.sbs
```

but when i search with query

```
uri:nntp\://msnews.microsoft.com/microsoft.public.windows.server.sbs
```

It returns zero results. The search query works with similar other uri (nntp://msnews.microsoft.com/microsoft.public.windows.windowsxp.general) though.

What am i missing here?

Comment: have you tried issuing the query through the Solr console? don't know about pysolr but I just tested this on pure Solr and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If your search URI is similar to
`/select?uri%3Anntp*&rows=0`
you should still be able to get a good idea of how many items in that field begin with nntp without even returning any rows, the `numFound` attribute of the result tag should tell you.

If this is blank, I would check your logfile. It is entirely likely you're adding documents with commit turned off. I would use the command line scripts to force things to commit and refresh the readers:

```
sync
bin/commit 
sync
bin/readercycle
```

Then I would issue that search again and see if you can see your data again.